# Filter object by property that starts with any of array elements

Tags: javascript

I have an object of contacts where I need to filter by the country code, for which I need to check if the ID of the contact (phone number) starts with any of the selected country codes array.

```
var countries = ['1', '91', '55', '972'];

var allContacts = [
        {
            id: '9123242135321',
            name: 'Harun'
        },
        {
            id: '905366365289',
            name: 'Koray'
        },
        {
            id: '135366365277',
            name: 'Hayo'
        },
        {
            id: '963923824212',
            name: 'Bahaa'
        },
        {
            id: '513324515689',
            name: 'Hassan'
        }];
```

I am looking for an efficient one-line solution without looping, so what I have tried before is:

```
allContacts.filter(c => c.id.some(l => countries.includes(l)));
```

But that worked if the `id` parameter is an array, and it searches the whole number instead of the beginning, what is the efficient way to filter the contacts which their `id` key `startsWith` any of the `countries` array values?

Comment: "_one-line solution without looping_" Not possible without looping.

Comment: Have a look at [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate the countries and check with `startsWith`.

```js
const
    countries = ['1', '91', '55', '972'],
    allContacts = [{ id: '9123242135321', name: 'Harun' }, { id: '905366365289', name: 'Koray' }, { id: '135366365277', name: 'Hayo' }, { id: '963923824212', name: 'Bahaa' }, { id: '513324515689', name: 'Hassan' }];

console.log(allContacts.filter(({ id }) => countries.some(c => id.startsWith(c))));
```